# How to direct a dynamic url to a Drupal page

Tags: uri

I created a little web app that allows people to keep content on a page.  They can specify the url of the page.  Instead of accessing their page like this: http://example.com/stuff?page=their_url I want the url to be like this: http://example.com/stuff/their_url

But I can't figure out how to direct a dynamic url to a Drupal page.  I've even tried Apache redirects, but I can't get that working either.  I keep getting 404's.

I'm willing to use Apache rewrites to get to the right page.

I'm willing to point to a regular PHP file on the server and bootstrap Drupal, but so far I haven't been able to get that working.

I'm willing to put PHP code into a Drupal page.

I really don't want to write my own Drupal module, so if you want to offer some Drupal code, please tell me where to use it.

I'm willing to use a Drupal 7 module if you know of any.

Thanks a lot!

--
Magmatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few hours I finally got something working.  This is it:

In my .htaccess file I have a rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^fz/(.*) fz.php?page=$1
```

Then in my fz.php file I have this:

```
<?

$_GET["q"] = "filezone";

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

menu_execute_active_handler();
```

I have a Drupal page that I want to display.  It's url is set to be "filezone". In fz.php, it displays this page.  And on that page I can get the "page" value with $_GET["page"].

Answer (score 0):

i think that you can use the :
[function drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_goto/7)

but not sure if that is for your case.

Comment: Thanks, but this is an external redirect.  I want an internal redirect (so the user's browser doesn't see it).